# R - IDW interpolation using gstat

Tags: r, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

It contains two coordinate columns `dist` for distance in x direction and `rel_alt` for an altitude in y direction. The other two columns are the data points for each combination of those two coordinate values.

I am now trying to do a IDW interpolation on the `ff` column. This is what I tried:

```
#read the data
dat <- read.csv("data.csv")
#create the grid
x.range <- c(min(dat$dist), max(dat$dist))
y.range <- c(min(dat$rel_alt), max(dat$rel_alt))
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 1), 
                   y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 1))
#convert to SpatialPixels 
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
gridded(grd) <- TRUE

neighbors = length(dat$ff)
beta = 2

idw_ff = gstat(formula = ff ~ 1, 
                 data = dat, 
                 nmax = neighbors, 
                 set = list(idp = beta))

grid.ff <- predict(object = idw_ff, newdata = grd)
```

But I am getting an Error message saying:

```
Error in cbind(dataLst[[1]]$data@bbox[cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 2, 1,  : 
  trying to get slot "bbox" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object
```

I don't get the Error, as the `grd` data is an S4 object. And I am not really sure if that what I am doing even would work properly?

Answer (score 1):

At this point `dat` isn't a spatial object, so when `predict` refers back to it it can't get any spatial data:

```
idw_ff = gstat(formula = ff ~ 1, 
                 data = dat, 
                 nmax = neighbors, 
                 set = list(idp = beta))
```

make it spatial:

```
coordinates(dat)=~dist+rel_alt
```

and it works.

```
idw_ff = gstat(formula = ff ~ 1, 
                 data = dat, 
                 nmax = neighbors, 
                 set = list(idp = beta))

grid.ff <- predict(object = idw_ff, newdata = grd)
```

[Note this is going to take a while to compute, but `newdata=grd[1:100,]` shows it runs in principle]

Comment: That worked! For some reason I thought the problem originates from the grid itself not the actual data. Thanks! I can't accept the post as the answer, but will do as soon as I have enough reputation.